# XCode Modal VC is cut off if "view as:" differs

Tags: ios, xcode, modalviewcontroller

I don't know if this is a bug or what, I do use auto-layout and everything works fine except the modal view controllers.

---

IF the "view as:" option is the same as the Simulator's size, nothing is wrong with them. But when they differ, then the screen cuts some content off.

So if I do check "view as iPhone 8" and run it on a simulated iPhone 8 it is fine.

But if I do it on a simulated SE, it cuts off some content:

**But only if it is a modal view controller**

```
View as iPhone 8, Simulator as iPhone SE
```

[image]

```
View as iPhone SE, Simulator as iPhone SE
```

[image]

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing wrong here is that the mask (or whatever it is) that imposes the rounded corners is the wrong size.

Your corner-rounding code is probably in the wrong place — perhaps in `viewDidLoad`. That's a mistake because at the time `viewDidLoad` is called, your view has not yet achieved its final size.

Your first screen shot is a perfect case in point. The modal view is loaded at iPhone 8 width, and you do the corner rounding assuming that is its size. But then the view is reduced to the width of the iPhone SE, and so the rounding calculation ends up not fitting the actual size of the view.

The solution is simple: Move the corner-rounding code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Be careful, though: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` runs many times, so use a Bool flag to make sure you round the corners only once, the first time it is called.